# Python > Selenium: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have an script and when I run it, it shows the error:  DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
Could you help me? (I'm a beginner). Thanks!!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver')
```

Comment: What help do you need? Have you read [the fine documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_chrome/selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.html)?

Comment: You should make more effort and review updated documentation and use proper classes and methods instead of deprecated ones. That's exactly what selenium tells you.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have Selenium 4.6+, you no longer need to set the path, download drivers, etc. All you need is

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Selenium now has [DriverManager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/) which takes care of downloading, setting up, and maintaining drivers for you.

Comment: will it assume the same driver path or should they remove the old driver in `./chromedriver`

Comment: @merhoo I would delete all existing drivers from everywhere and let DriverManager take care of everything.